# Is there any function that calculate the ray direction using fisheye lens parameter in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

Given a pixel location, we can calculate the 3D xyz ray direction using the camera's intrinsic information.

But this problem is a little bit tricky with the fisheye lens model.

Is there any function that calculates the ray direction using the fisheye lens parameter in OpenCV?

Implementing this feature is not too difficult but I am asking to prevent reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cv::fisheye::undistortPoints()`

Pass an identity matrix for the new `P` camera matrix. That ought to yield suitable vectors (rays originating from the camera).

Comment: Thanks! But I guess that doesn't handle points near 180 degrees. Isn't it?

Comment: it should. the fisheye model of OpenCV only covers <180 degrees anyway. anything >= 180 degrees is called "super fisheye". I have no idea what these models look like. in any case, the same principles apply: understand the model (equations), walk the pixel backwards through the physics/geometry, get a ray

Comment: OCam's calibration model easily covers any angle but Opencv's model uses a pinhole projection model which should give severe uncertainty when it's over 160. Simply when there is 1 pixel uncertainty it propagates hugely in the normalized space if it is around the image circle edge.I reviewed the model all day today and concluded that it's not possible to get a stable recovery with the pinhole projection model in the Opencv's fisheye class. I see the only way is directly converting the incidence angle to r as in ocam model. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

simple answer is no! The Kannala model that is used in opencv does not have inverse model!
What the guys in opencv do is as follows:
they assume a perspective camera with focal 1,
thus camera matrix K
[1,0,0
0,1,0
0,0, 1]
Then they apply back projection to rays, and for the very same rays, they apply the forward model into the fish-eye camera and apply interpolation for the intensity values
This is fairly correct, since the perspective camera will not cover information outside 180 degrees and obviously will introduce severe intensity discrepancy (because of the interpolation)
The correct way is to use the OmniCam model of Scaramuzza that supports an backprojection model (image 2ray) and has already a stable lib for all of the operations.
Moreover, for peculiar cameras, the ray bending polynomial (that opencv wrongly named "lens distortion coefficients"?!?!)
can be of suitable order that covers the camera model in a better way!
Cheers!

Comment: you are mixing up the models and how they're specified (lens distortion coefficients). there's nothing wrong.

Comment: no, I am not missing anything...
you are starting from deliberately chosen projective model, defined by the new Camera perspective matrix, the code is applying backward projection (img to world ray), then it returns back to the Kannala model, applies the bending polynomial by polynomial coeffs (called distortion coeffs), interpolates, and then remaps the values to the desired perspective grid...while in the reality, it should be directly...there should be inverse polynomial model of that coeffs, a second set of coeffs, that returns the non-bended world ray. But this is not the solution asked